# C++ Excluding non-integer user inputs

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a number-guessing game where the user is asked to input a four-digit number. It is possible, however, that the user inputs less or more than four digits and/or a non-integer input (i.e. invalid input). My code stores the user input into an integer-type array. I just realized now that my code will still recognize "invalid inputs" as valid since the array where the input is being stored is declared as an integer-type. Below is a portion of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void guess(int num_guess[], int size);

int main(){
        int list[4];
        guess(list, 4);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            cout << list[i];
        }
        cout << endl;
}
void guess(int num_guess[], int size){
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--){
        num_guess[i] = number%10;
        number /= 10;
    }
}
```

`cout << list[i];` isn't really part of the original code, but this was how I found out that invalid inputs are still accepted. I encountered a similar problem before when I was making a rational roots calculator program in Python, but it was much easier then to detect and exclude unwanted inputs. My question is, how do I fix my code so that it can detect invalid inputs and output something like "Invalid input" and then proceed to ask the user for another input.

Comment: Don't have time to make a full answer, but you could read into a `std::string`, or a whole line at a time with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), then attempt to parse the value into an `int` (even with a `std::istringstream`, though that's a bit heavyweight). This gives you more flexibility in dealing with failures, without messing up your input stream.

Comment: I have a function for the randomly generated number (number being guessed) which is also stored into an int array. Would it be more convenient if I just used a string to store both the random and guess numbers?

Comment: @user657267 Yes, it does matter that the user inputs exactly four digits.

Comment: try `do { cin >> number; } while (number<=pow(10, size-1) || number>=pow(10, size+1));`

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик the logic is wrong. It should be `... while (number<=pow(10, size-1)` **&&** `number>=pow(10, size+1));`

Comment: Not! You wrong! need **||** ! Check it. Condition `while (number<=pow(10, size-1) && number>=pow(10, size+1))` always `false`

Comment: i found error my code, need `do { cin >> number; } while (number<pow(10, size-1) || number>=pow(10, size));` but need **||**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a function to check if a `string` is a 4 digit positive integer. If the number could be negative, you just need to check if the `s[0] == '-'`.

```
bool check(string &s){
    if(s.size() != 4) return false;
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        if(s[i] < '0' || s[i] > '9') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following is a function to convert a `string` to an `int`:

```
#include <stringstream>
int strToInt(string &s){
    stringstream ss(s);
    int ans;
    ss >> ans;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Since, I need to check if the `string` is not exactly four digits, wouldn't this be better `if(s.size() != 4)`?

Comment: Yes you are right, I thought the user should input an integer with at most four digits. I will update the code.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude non integer inputs try the following:

```
void skip_to_int(){
// if is not an integer
if(cin.fail()){
   // check character type
   cin.clear();
   char ch;
   while(cin>>ch){
      // throw away non digits
      if(isdigit(ch)){
          // put back if digit to be written
          cin.unget();
          return;}
   }

}
else error ("no input");
}
```

And your input prompt function will look like this:

```
cout << "Please enter an integer" << endl;
int n=0;
if(cin>>n){
// integer OK, proceed
}
else{
    cout << "That was not a numeric value, try again." << endl;
    skip_to_int();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Beware, it uses C++11. Certainly not necessary if you use `std::stringstream`, but this should work pretty well.

I presume you don't want negative numbers. I also presume that any number of 0's in front doesn't make the number a 4-digit number. It will cut off padded 0's, so 01234 is a 4 digit number, but 0123 isn't.

```
void guess(int num_guess[], int size) 
{
    int number;

    // if the length of the number isn't 4, try again until it is
    do { 
       std::cin >> number; 
       if(std::to_string(number).length() != size) 
          std::cout << "You messed up the input. How hard could it be? Try again..." << std::endl;
    } while(std::to_string(number).length() != size);

    // by now, the size is definitely 4. insert it by digit into num_guess
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i++) {
      num_guess[i] = number%10;
      number /= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add **#include "math.h"**

and change **guess**

```
void guess(int num_guess[], int size){
  int number = 0;
  bool firstTime = true;
  do 
  {
    if (!firstTime)
      cout << " Error, try again " << endl;
    firstTime = false;
    cin >> number;
  } while (number<pow(10, size-1) || number>=pow(10, size));
  for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--){
      num_guess[i] = number%10;
      number /= 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <limits>                                                               

int main() {                                                                    
    int i = 0;                                                                  

    std::cout << "Please enter a number with four digits: ";                    
    while( !(std::cin >> i) || !(i / 1000.0f >= 1.0f) )                          
    {                                                                           
        std::cin.clear();                                                       
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');     
        std::cout << "Invalid entry." << std::endl;                             
        std::cout << "Please enter a number with four digits: ";                
    }                                                                           
}
```

the std::cin.clear() clears all errors flags on current stream structure and std::cin.ignore() cleans up the input stream itself. Once we don't know the size of stream 'til this operation I have used the maximum possible value of a stream size to make sure any stream length could be cleaned.

Comment: we do not know in advance the number of digits. Your code is a special case!

Comment: I believe I misunderstood the problem just reading the description. I will fix the code as soon as I have time today and update it here.